# Adding CoreBluetooth assembly in xamarin cross platform project

Tags: xamarin

I am developing a xamarin cross platform project in visual studio environment, I want to add CoreBluetooth library to my project. According to this link [xamarin link](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/CoreBluetooth/)

I am new to develop xamarin.Please let me know how to add this library.

Comment: `CoreBluetooth` is an iOS framework and is already bound into Xamarin.iOS so there is nothing to "add", you can access native APIs from .NetStd via a dependency service  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: Thank you, I don't get what kind of interface has to created.